# "cannot be cast" in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I tried to run a simple Spring (4.0.0 release) program using Eclipse. But I'm stuck in one place. It says "cannot be cast".

**Drawing.java**

```
package org.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Drawing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("org/spring/spring.xml");
        Square myBean= (Square) context.getBean("square");
        myBean.paint();
    }
```

**Square.java**

```
package org.spring;

public class Square {
    public void paint() {
        System.out.println("Square Drawn");
    }
}
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"  
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd"> 

<beans>
  <bean id="square" class="org.spring.Drawing">
  </bean>
</beans>
```

When I tried to execute it it prints:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.spring.Drawing cannot be cast to org.spring.Square
    at org.spring.Drawing.main(Drawing.java:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<bean id="square" class="org.spring.Drawing">
```

should be

```
<bean id="square" class="org.spring.Square">
```

`Drawing` is not a sub type of `Square` and therefore cannot be cast to `Square`.